# F310 Gamepad detects as HID Keyboard and mouse (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, game-controller, logitech-gamepad

I have a Logitech 310 Gamepad and windows 10.  Sometimes the device works, but very rarely and I have no idea what triggers it to work properly.

Most of the time, the controller registers as an HID Mouse and an HID Keyboard (though I gather that it's supposed to show up as a Gamepad F310 when using X-input or Dual Action gamepad when using D-input).

Occasionally the gamepad gets detected properly and it works like it should. Sometimes this happens after waiting a while with it plugged in. Other times it's in the midst of flipping switches and settings. The gamepad has never worked immediately after being plugged in.

I have run the provided software (for windows 10, 64 bit), but the readme does not list windows 10 as an OS that it was designed for and it's dated 2010. 
I have rebooted with the controller plugged in. 
I have switched which USB port the controller is plugged into. 
I have made sure that the switch on the back is set to X, though I have also tried it set to D and tried switching it after it didn't seem to detect as the other. 
I have run windows 10's Set up a USB gamepad controller functionality (this worked once, but has not since). Most of the time the device doesn't show up on here at all.
I have run the profiler while trying to get it recognized as I read that was someone's solution on the forum (though I have yet to see anyone claim their devices are showing up as HID keyboards or mice).

I am willing to try anything suggested, including things I have already tried if it means that I might have a reliable way of making this controller work.